# How to load external text data into C#?

Tags: c#

I have a text file named `my_date.txt` containing following data:

```
1 Adam
2 Steve
3 Lisa
4 Josh
.....
```

The text file may be very long. I am trying to load this data contained in this text file into an array in C# so that I could do an operation. In `sas` I just use input. In `VBA` I just refer the cells, assuming I make it in excel. But here with C#, I have no idea at all.

Answer (score 3):

In `C#` you can do that using `File.ReadLines` method and [`LINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
var values = File
            .ReadLines("filePath") // 1
            .Select(x => x.Split())  // 2
            .Select(x => new { Id = x[0], Name = string.Join(" ", x.Skip(1) }) // 3
            .ToArray(); // 4
```

1. Read all lines from the file
2. `Split` each line by white-space
3. Create an anonymous object for each line that contains two property `Id` (number), and the `Name`, I used `string.Join` because your names might contain *white-spaces*.You can use a custom class instead of anonymous type that would be more appropriate.
4. Convert the result into an array.

Comment: ..not sure I would label that "easily" for a complete beginner. There are easily 10 different topics in this single piece of code..

Comment: You should explain what's an anonymous type :D

Comment: #3 Should read: `.Select(x => new { Id = x[0], Name = string.Join(" ", x.Skip(1)) } )`

Answer (score 3):

**#1 Simple For**

You can use [File.ReadAllLines](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readalllines) to put the lines of a text file into a string array.

```
string[] names = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\my_date.txt");
```

And then parse the data to remove the `1, 2, 3, etc` before the names

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    names[i] = names[i].Split()[1];    
}
```

**#2 LINQ**

Using the simple for loop will work fine, but alternatively you can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
string[] names = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\my_date.txt")
    .Select(str => str.Split()).Select(name => name[1]).ToArray();
```

In the event that you don't need a number prefix, you can simply use the `ReadAllLines` method without the `Split()`

Comment: @user3147731 It would be nice if you accepted either Selman's or my answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: i found both of your answers helpful....i just start learning....the ultimate goal is to build an app for myself....so the more i learn the better. thank you.

Comment: I see, no problem, I mean click the little "check" mark next to an answer to mark this post as solved :)